# What does the for loop condition (str1[i] && str2[i]) mean?

Tags: c++

```
for (int i = 0; str1[i] && str2[i]; i++)
```

What does `str1[i] && str2[i]` mean? I have known the middle part of a for loop to be a condition but how is that a condition? What is it checking?

Comment: The key is both `str1` and `str2` must be valid, *nul-terminated* C-strings. C-strings end with ASCII `'\0'` (which has a value of `0`). See: [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/). So long as both `str1` and `str2` are valid strings, the loop will iterate over the characters in each until the end of the shortest string is reached.

Answer (score 3):

This loop keeps going until either one of the values is falsy. Most likely, both of them are C-style strings (which are simple `char` arrays or pointers, terminated with a `NUL` character, `'\0'`), and the loop is intended to continue until it's reached the end of the shortest string (the first one in which it finds `NUL`).

Answer (score 2):

This expression:

```
str1[i] && str2[i]
```

Is equivalent to

```
(str1[i] != '\0') && (str2[i] != '\0')
```

The for loop terminates when either `str1[i]` or `str2[i]` is the end of the string.

In other words, when the for loop terminates, `i` is the length of the shorter of `str1` and `str2`. (Although by then, `i` is out scope).

Comment: Asking a question here on behalf of a new contributor (@Rilesh Khatri): “how will the loop terminate here when either of strings reach the null value the statement clearly says && and as per my knowledge when logic AND (&&) is used both the conditions needs to be true in order to end the loop”

Answer (score 0):

str1 and str2 are probably c strings (char *, char []) so the for loop iterates till either str1[i] or str2[i] are `\0` which is the string terminator.  The string `"hi"` is a more convenient way to write  `{ 'h', 'i', '\0' }`.